# Customize Invoice PDF Template

Tags: template, invoice

In one of our over seas stores, the Invoice PDF Printout is printing what looks like html encoded chars (á), We need to correct this, I have reviewed the following links, but none of it seems to match up or appears to be out of date, especially the first link which looks like the easiest solution.

References:

1. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/custom-pdf-templates/
2. http://www.xpcdesign.com/2008/12/edit-the-magento-invoice-pdf-templates/ (2008)
3. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/ (2011)
4. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf

Comment: The first link only applies to Magento Go which you might be on or not. If you can post a pdf example with the wrongly encoded character it will be easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: change the font to freeserif.

Comment: Do I have to provide a ttf file, or is there some way to specify that font without a file?

Comment: I changed the font files to FreeSerif however the encoding is still there... Any ideas on what other fonts I can try?

Comment: Well changing it is a very complicated and time consuming task. I've spent over a week for this and finally got it looking professional. I've my template as an extension on magento connect if you would be interested http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/s4-customizable-invoice-template.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an encoding issue, I had to change UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1